# Searching in all files since last commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there any way to search in all modified and staged (git) files. I want to look for any debug logging that I may have put and remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what patterns to look for (e.g : `console.log`, `DEBUG` or some specific word ... ), you can use `git grep` with the `--cahed` option :

```
# will loook in all staged files for the target pattern :
git grep --cached 'console\.log'

# you can add '-i' for a case insensitive search :
git grep -i --cached 'console\.log'
```

---

You can run this from any command line, I don't know if the git interface for intellij has a menu entry for this command.